# Java Database Connection without path

Tags: database, javafx, path, connection

I have a question about Java and Databases. I am using an Microsoft Access Database and in order to be connected at the database i have to give full path at the driver.The Path Looks like the following. Also this path doesn't help me with the program portability.

`String DBPath = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//theuser//Desktop//CostumerAppData.accdb";`

Can i have database inside my project and give a simple path in order to be connected?

Thank you in advance about your responses.

Comment: Use an embedded database. Not sure if MS access has an embedded database, but there are other options available.

Comment: i was wondering if i could have the db file stored to a package or folder inside my project that's what i am searching for . i will keep in mind the embedded database option..

Comment: Have a look at [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

Comment: I know SQLite and i was working with this. it's the same situation with this one. My problem is the portability not the database :)

Comment: what about portability? I am sure SQLite is portable. You can create a database where your application is installed or on some temporary location on the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ucanaccess supports both relative and absolute path.  If you're using a relative path, it must be relative to the current working directory. Path class (java.nio.file) may help . Maybe I'll be able to simplify this case solution in the next versions.